# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Here is my Swift 2 code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellwithIdentifier: forWithIdentifier("idCellChannel", forIndexPath: indexPath as IndexPath)

    let channelTitleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel
    let thumbnailImageView = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIImageView

    let channelDetails = channelsDataArray[indexPath.row]
    channelTitleLabel.text = channelDetails["title"] as? String

    // Error  Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
    thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: (channelDetails["thumbnail"] as? String)!)!)!)

    return cell
}
```

Please give me a solution for Swift 3.

Comment: Try with `let channelDetails = channelsDataArray[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String, String>

Comment: Please update your question with the declaration of `channelsDataArray`.

Comment: Also clarify which line is actually giving the error. Did your error comment apply to the line before it or after it?

Comment: Are you aware that you can create custom table view cells with IBOutlets directly in Interface Builder to avoid the `viewWithTag` dance? And `cell` is `let` and non-optional.

Comment: what is `channelDetails`? you just forgot to write its type...

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler that `channelsDataArray[indexPath.row]` is a `Dictionary` so that you can `subscript` it with. Try below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let channelsDataArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()//This is your array of dictionaries
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idCellChannel", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let channelTitleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel
    let thumbnailImageView = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIImageView
    let channelDetails = channelsDataArray[indexPath.row]
    channelTitleLabel.text = channelDetails["title"] as? String
    thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: (channelDetails["thumbnail"] as? String)!)! as URL)! as Data)

    return cell
}
```

And also check for `nil` since you are force unwrapping at most of the places which would your app crashing. Use `guard let` or `if let`s.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change the declaration of `channelsDataArray` to specify what's in that array. Then you wouldn't need a cast on every line of code that accesses it.

Comment: Yes thats true, updated my code with that and Swift3